# Quantization of tensor perturbation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, cosmology

I have a problem when I am reading the paper "Probing the early universe with inflationary gravitational waves", written by Latham A. Boyle and Paul J. Steinhardt. Before I state my problem, I would like to state the background of this question. In this paper, they used the perturbed flat FRW metric as the background spacetime:

\begin{equation}
ds^{2} = a^{2}(\tau)[ -d\tau^{2}  + (\delta_{ij} + h_{ij})dx^{i}dx^{j} ] 
\end{equation}
Where $h_{ij}$ is the tensor perturbation term. Then, they plug this into Einstein-Hilbert action and expand it into second order in $h_{ij}$.

\begin{equation}
S = \int d\tau d^{3}x \sqrt{- \bar{g}} \frac{\bar{g}^{\mu \nu}}{64 \pi G} \partial_{\mu} h_{ij} \partial_{\nu}h_{ij} + \frac{1}{2}\Pi_{ij}h_{ij}
\end{equation}
Where $\Pi_{ij}$ is the anisotropic stress. Moreover, they used Fourier transformation to transfrom tensor perturbation $h_{ij}$ and anisotropic stress $\Pi_{ij}$ to the momentum space, denoted as $h_{\textbf{k}}$ and $\pi_{\textbf{k}}$ respectively. Lastly, they plugged the Fourier transformation of $h_{ij}$ and $\Pi_{ij}$ into the Einstein-Hilbert action, resulting in equation(7) of the attached picture.

[image]

My problem is that in fact we cannot directly quantize the tensor perturbation as same as quantisation of scalar field/electromagnetic field. However, the writers can impose the commutation relationship of $h_{\textbf{k}}$ and its conjugate momentum $\pi_{\textbf{k}}$. Could anyone explain the reason of quantising tensor perturbation to me?

Comment: What is your reason for thinking that one cannot directly quantize tensor perturbations?

Comment: @Avantgarde. My reason is that quantization of metric relates to quantum gravity. However, my Professor of particle physics course told me that quantisation of gravity was not that simple due to renormalisation problem. Therefore, I am struggling can I quantize the tensor perturbation in such way.

Comment: You're correct that quantizing the metric is a step towards quantum gravity. But there are many aspects to quantum gravity, and a simple quantization of tensor modes is harmless. Quantum gravity is important only at very high energy scales (near Planck scale). We know that everything is fine and consistent with a low-energy description of quantum gravity. Non-renormalizability of GR is an issue, but there are other issues as well. Actually, non-renormalizability is not a problem at all if you are only interested in low-energy behavior: they're then very robust.